# C++ Templates. Equal dependent names

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to write small example with explicit template specified for dependent names. I wrote the following code and did't get an error about missed "*template*" keyword in "*x.test< T >()*".

```
template< typename T >
struct Entity1
{
    template< typename U >
    void test() {}
};

struct Entity2
{
    template< typename T >
    void test()
    {
        Entity1< T > x;
        return x.test< T >();
    }
};
```

Then I tried to rename *Entity2::test* method to *Entity2::test2* and finally got the following error: "error: expected primary-expression before '>' token"

```
template< typename T >
struct Entity1
{
    template< typename U >
    void test() {}
};

struct Entity2
{
    template< typename T >
    void test2()
    {
        Entity1< T > x;
        return x.test< T >();
    }
};
```

It works only if I add "*x.template test< T >()*". I know about this keyword and that it should be used here because "*test*" (in expression x.test) is dependent name. But I definitely don't understand why it's not required in case of equal method names.

Comment: Could be just a gcc bug. Clang doesn't compile this.

Comment: Both compilers reject first snippet as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4ab20b6677b7bf7).

Comment: @Jarod42 gcc 6.3 accepts